# Printing the array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, struct

The `addInfo()` adds information into the array of structures and the function `printList()` outputs all of the elements of that array. But my printList() is outputting only the last element that was added. What can be wrong? Does it add elemets into the array incorrectly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//structure Location
typedef struct Location{
    char locName[35];
    char locDesc[85];
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
} LocationArray;

void addInfo(LocationArray **myArray, int*, int*);
void printList(LocationArray **myArray, int*);
void quitProgram();
void resizeArray(LocationArray **myArray, int*);

//Menu that receives the user input
//and performs corresponding operations based
//on the menu choice
void printMenu(LocationArray **myArray, int *count, int *max){
    printf("Hello! Please choose from the menu: \n");
    printf("Type 'A' or 'a' for adding additional location to the array\n");
    printf("Type 'P' or 'p' for printing the current list of locations\n");
    printf("Type 'Q' or 'q' to quit the program\n");

    char input = 0;
    scanf(" %c", &input);

    //Handles the invalid character input
    //exits if the character does not correspond
    //to the valid menu option
    while(input != 'A' && input != 'a'
        && input != 'P' && input != 'p'
        && input != 'Q' && input != 'q'){
            printf("Invalid character! Try entering a char again: \n");
            scanf(" %c", &input);
    }
    //Calls other functions
    //based on the character input
    switch(input){
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
        addInfo(myArray, count, max); //Calls function that adds more locations into the array
        break;
    case 'P':
    case 'p':
        printList(myArray, count); //Calls the function that prints the current list of locations
        break;
    case 'Q':
    case 'q':
        quitProgram(); //Calls the function that terminates the program
        break;
    }
}

//Adds info into the array of structures
void addInfo(LocationArray **myArray, int *count, int *numberOfLoc){

    if(*count == *numberOfLoc){ // Checks if the array is already full
        resizeArray(myArray, numberOfLoc); //Resizes the array if it's full

        printf("Please enter the name for the location:\n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", &(*myArray)->locName); //Gets the user input for the Location Name
        printf("\nNow enter the description:\n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", &(*myArray)->locDesc); //Gets the user input for the Location Description
        printf("\nNow enter the value for the latitude:\n");
        scanf("%f", &(*myArray)->latitude); //Gets the user input for the Latitude
        printf("\nNow enter the value for the longitude:\n");
        scanf("%f", &(*myArray)->longitude); //Gets the user input for the Latitude

        (*count)++; //Increment the count
    }
    else{ //Else, a used fills it out
        printf("Please enter the name for the location:\n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", &(*myArray)->locName); //Gets the user input for the Location Name
        printf("\nNow enter the description:\n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", &(*myArray)->locDesc); //Gets the user input for the Location Description
        printf("\nNow enter the value for the latitude:\n");
        scanf("%f", &(*myArray)->latitude); //Gets the user input for the Latitude
        printf("\nNow enter the value for the longitude:\n");
        scanf("%f", &(*myArray)->longitude); //Gets the user input for the Latitude

        (*count)++; //Increment the count
    }
}

//Resizes(doubles) the array size if the max limit is achieved
void resizeArray(LocationArray **myArray, int *numberOfLoc){
    *numberOfLoc = *numberOfLoc * 2; //Double the size

    LocationArray *temp;
    temp = (LocationArray*)realloc(*myArray, *numberOfLoc *sizeof(LocationArray)); //Reallocates more memory

    //Checks if the memory heap is exhausted
    if(temp == NULL){
        printf("The memory heap is exhausted!\n");
    }
    else{
        *myArray = temp; //Copy from the temp struct variable to myArray
    }
}

//Prints all of the elements of the array
void printList(LocationArray **myArray, int *count){
    if((*count) == 0){ //If the list is empty, then return
        printf("The list is empty!");
        return;
    }

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < (*count); i++){
        printf("Location name: %s\n", (*myArray[i]).locName);
        printf("Description: %s\n", (*myArray[i]).locDesc);
        printf("Latitude: %f\n", (*myArray[i]).latitude);
        printf("Longitude: %f\n", (*myArray[i]).longitude);
    }
}

//Quits the program
void quitProgram(){
    printf("Bye!");
    exit(0);
}


int main()
{
    printf("How many locations would you like to be inside the array?\n");
    int numberOfLoc = 0; //variable for storing the size of the LocationArray
    scanf(" %d", &numberOfLoc); //gets the user input and stores in numerOfLoc

    LocationArray *myArray; //declares a LocationArray with the size of numberOfLoc
    myArray = (LocationArray*)malloc(numberOfLoc*sizeof(LocationArray));

    int count = 0;
    while(1){
        //Prints the menu
        printMenu(&myArray, &count, &numberOfLoc);
    }
    //Free the pointer
    free(myArray);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `printList`, you have the lines

```
for(i = 0; i < (*count); i++){
    printf("Location name: %s\n", (*myArray[i]).locName);
    printf("Description: %s\n", (*myArray[i]).locDesc);
    printf("Latitude: %f\n", (*myArray[i]).latitude);
    printf("Longitude: %f\n", (*myArray[i]).longitude);
}
```

Use of `*myArray[i]` is incorrect. That is equivalent to `*(myArray[i])`. You need to use: `(*myArray)[i]`.

```
for(i = 0; i < (*count); i++){
    printf("Location name: %s\n", (*myArray)[i].locName);
    printf("Description: %s\n", (*myArray)[i].locDesc);
    printf("Latitude: %f\n", (*myArray)[i].latitude);
    printf("Longitude: %f\n", (*myArray)[i].longitude);
}
```

You can make code in `printList` simpler by changing the argument to 
`LocationArray *myArray` and `int count`.

```
void printList(LocationArray *myArray, int count){
    if(count == 0){ //If the list is empty, then return
        printf("The list is empty!");
        return;
    }

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        printf("Location name: %s\n", myArray[i].locName);
        printf("Description: %s\n", myArray[i].locDesc);
        printf("Latitude: %f\n", myArray[i].latitude);
        printf("Longitude: %f\n", myArray[i].longitude);
    }
}
```

and make sure to change the call to the function. Instead of

```
printList(myArray, count);
```

use

```
printList(*myArray, *count);
```

**Further cleanup**

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", &(*myArray)->locName);
scanf(" %[^\n]", &(*myArray)->locDesc);
```

are wrong on two accounts.

1. You don't need to use `&`.
2. You need to use the `count`-th element of `myArray`. The above always store the data in the first element of `myArray`.

use

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", (*myArray)[*count].locName);
scanf(" %[^\n]", (*myArray)[*count].locDesc);
```

Modify the other `scanf` lines also to:

```
scanf("%f", &(*myArray)[*count].latitude);
scanf("%f", &(*myArray)[*count].longitude);
```

Comment: Shouldnt I change it to `printList(*myArray, count);` instead of ` `printList(*myArray, *count);`?? @RSahu

Comment: @John, No. In the function you are calling `printList`, `count` is of type `int*`. Hence, it will be necessary to use `*count`.

Comment: Why cant I do  scanf("%f", myArray[*count]->longitude);? What should I do instead? @RSahu

Comment: @John, you will need to use `scanf("%f", &myArray[*count]->longitude)` since `scanf` needs an address of a `float` when the format specification is `%f`.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, @RSahu, I changed everything like you said, but when i try to enter the info the second time it stops working. Could you please take a look if `(*count)++` proper in the code? @RSahu

Comment: @John, I had errors in my suggested code. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But could you explain one of them, for example:`(*myArray)[*count].locName`. My is it supposed to be casted? and why the previous code didnt work although the logic was fine? @RSahu

Comment: @John, The previous code suffered from the same error that I pointed out was the problem in `printList`.